# Plotting with literals

Tags: plot

I can plot functions with numbers using pgfplots but how can I plot something like the next image?

[image: function with literals]

The curved part corresponds to an exponential with negative argument.

Comment: Can you edit-in what you have?  It will be easier for someone here to control the labeling specifically if they can start from a plot that looks *sort of* like what you want :)  That said, I would probably do this with just plain ole' TikZ using control curves.

Comment: Plotting a line and then an exponential controlling their domain it is not what you want?

Comment: @Astrinus Something like it. But I don't know how to put that the function begins in Vo and end in Vs because aren't numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node [below] {$t$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5)  node [left] {$v(t)$};

\draw [domain=-1:0, scale=1,red,very thick] plot (\x,1);
\draw [domain=0:5, scale=1,red,very thick] plot (\x,{3*(1-exp(-\x))+1}); 
\draw [domain=0:5, scale=1, dashed,blue] plot (\x,4); 

\node[right] at (0,1) {$V_0$} ;
\node[left]   at (0,4) {$V_s$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```