# How do i can plot functions with undefined domain in Pgfplots like that?

Tags: pgfplots

[I need that plot in latex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5x6E.png)

Where i can learn how to plot function like in books?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: i found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204096/plotting-with-literals). but idk how to plot on x-axis a and b

Comment: If you know the function you want to draw, you ca use the link you provided. If this just a rough sketch of an unknown function, you will have to draw it using Ti*k*Z commands. You can have a quick look at [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to plot something is to use [GeoGebra software](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en) (as an example). You should download the app and then export it as in the following example: [Need help to export tikz code from geogebra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445331/need-help-to-export-tikz-code-from-geogebra)